# How can my node.js server on AWS handle multiple users generating images when node calls Python program?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have containerized node.js code that runs on ECS. When multiple users use node.js to call a .py image generating problem, only 1 user gets the image, the rest get errors. I wonder if it appropriate to use Lambda so that the image generation multithreads.

For some reason, the containerized code which uses docker works locally, but not on AWS when multiple users access the .py function.

Answer (score 0):

If users send images from mobile application, you can use `aws-sdk` to upload images from mobile device to AWS S3, and configure Lambda trigger for image upload.
This Lambda will process image data and return you the result.
Since Lambda from serverless world, it can handle really big amount of invocations.
So, in case if you/your team can add aws-sdk to mobile application, it's nice approach to upload image directly from device to S3, trigger Lambda to image processing and change user's data in some storage.

If you have untrusted environment, like user's browser, it's not O.K. to upload image directly from browser to S3, since to achieve this goal you have to provide AWS access keys.
So, in this case, it's O.K. to upload image to server and transfer image from server to S3.

After this, the logic keeps the same: trigger AWS Lambda, process data and update it in storage.

This behaviour will reduce load to the server and allows you to work on features, instead of working on image storing and other stuff, which will just bother your server.

Comment: It comes from the browser. The server is on node.js and builds the image with a .py file. Is it possible that node.js itself is crashing because it can't handle the images from two or more users?

Comment: About crashing, it really depends on your code, but if you're using image processing in separate process, with some kind of `spawn` or `exec`, it should work just fine. 
Here is nice article about processes in node https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/ 
But if you have script in different language, it really would be easier and robust to manage flow with Lambda. Take a look at this framework to manage lambda https://serverless.com/